# List of characters between two parenthesis plus a number

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to do a predicate ***parlist(list,num,all).***

**"list"** is basically a list of characters (for example ['a','b','c']), **"num"** is just a natural number, and **"all"** is the list that concatenate the list plus the number, except if the length of elements in the original list is 2 or more, then the output list **"all"** has to be between two parenthesis excluding the number.

Example for a list with length >=2:

```
parlist(['a','b','c'],3,R).
```

Output should be:

```
R=['(','a','b','c',')',3]
```

Example for a list with length <2:

```
parlist(['a'],2,R).
```

Output should be:

```
R=['a',2]
```

I'm a little bit lost with prolog, so i dont see how to start, please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of Prolog is pattern matching. You have three cases, right?

- **The empty list**
  Just make put the number in a list: `[ 3 ]`
- **Lists of length 1**
  Append the number to the list: `[ a , 3 ]`
- **Lists of length > 1**
  Enclose the list in parentheses and add the number at the end: `[ '(', a, b, ')', 3 ]`.

For this you don't even need to iterate over the list. You just need to pattern-match in the head of your predicate clause.

**Case 1: the empty list.** This is easy:

```
parlist( [], N, [N] ).
```

**Case 2: Lists of length 1.** This is just as easy:

```
parlist( [X], N, [X,N] ).
```

**Case 3: Lists of length > 1.** A little more complex. You could use built-in here, or roll your own.

*Builtins:* We can  use `append/3` to effect here:

```
parlist( [X,Y|Zs], N, R ) :- append( ['(',X,Y|Zs], [')',N], R ).
```

*Roll Your Own:* You can roll your own almost as easily. We'll use a little specialized helper predicate here:

```
parlist( [X,Y|Zs], N, ['(' | R ] ) :- parlist1( ['(',X,Y|Zs], N, R ).

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% If the list is of length >= 2, add the 1st two elements to the
% result list, and
% - recurse down on the tail.
%
% If the list is of length 0 or 1, we're done: close out the result with
% - the last element of the list (if present),
% - the lead-out parenthesis and
% - the number
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
parlist1( [X,Y|Zs] , N , [X,Y|R] ) :- parlist1( Zs , N , R ).
parlist1( []       , N , [  ')',N] ).
parlist1( [X]      , N , [X,')',N] ).
```

Comment: In case 3, you could use the clause ```parlist([X,Y|Zs], N, R) :- append(['(',X,Y|Zs], [')',N], R).```.

Comment: The third parameter of the helper predicate can be avoided, if the open parenthesis is inserted as first item of the list when that predicate is called for the first time.

Comment: Updated my answer to include your suggestions. I had thought about the last bit — injecting the lead-in parenthesis in the call to the helper, but it felt... irregular. But it does make the whole thing simpler!